# C++ gui and console application

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, console-application

Could I use gui for taking the input from the user and use console to print the output ?
by other words, I mean could I mix both the windows or gui c++ with console application in one application ?

Comment: Yes you can. Why not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840942/visual-studio-2012-c-standard-output/13841522#13841522

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with a normal GUI application of your choice. Calling [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will then add a console window to your application.

Comment: Or you can start with a console application, and from there create any number of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, on linux it's will be almost from box on windows you must create console for application.What is your platform ?