# Batch file not show output when running exe

Tags: c++, batch-file

This is my build.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal
call "%VS120COMNTOOLS%"\\vsvars32.bat
echo Deleting old exe...
del build_win32\dist\bin\Whitedrop_d.exe
cd build_win32
echo Building As Debug
msbuild /detailedsummary /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x86 /t:build ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
echo Done building, Exiting.
cd dist\bin\
Whitedrop_d.exe
cd ../../../
endlocal
```

But when I run everything works perfectly, it builds and run, but nothing is logged when running my exe. If I try to add `cout << 'hi world' << endl` in main it compiles and run but I don't see Hi world in cmd prompt (but the GUI shows). Is there a way to show cmd output in same window?

Comment: I make the application subsystem console and I get the console output. Or allocate a console. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840942/visual-studio-2012-c-standard-output/13841522#13841522

Comment: On top of that for applications that I have both a GUI and a console I control this using command line arguments. If I pass a command line argument on some of my applications I don't create a GUI window.

Comment: @drescherjm i need both. It's based on ogre so... Will try or this tomorrow

Comment: Thank you editbin worked :) Is there a way w/ cmake