# printf doesn't print any message from dll library

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll

I have problem in printing messages from ".dll" library created in visual studio 2019.
I don't receive any errors or warnings. `printf` or `std::cout` just do nothing. Everything worked fine in visual studio 2010. I tried to compare project properties between vs2019 and vs2010 versions. But I didn't notice anything that may effect output. 
Here is simple example that shows how I expect to receive messages from this library:

```
#define DLLReturnType __declspec(dllexport)

DLLReturnType int add3DArraysLib(int value)
{

printf("Received value - %d", value);

return value + 1;

}
```

Comment: ***I don't receive any errors or warnings. printf or std::cout just do nothing*** Is your application a console or windows application? if you are using a windows GUI application and don't have a console printf and couts will not be seen.

Comment: Hi, it would help enormously if you could show the code you expect to respond and the code that calls it.

Comment: I wrote this answer years ago about creating a console in a GUI application: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840942/visual-studio-2012-c-standard-output/13841522#13841522](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840942/visual-studio-2012-c-standard-output/13841522#13841522)

Comment: It's CUDA 10.2 Runtime that builds Dynamic-link library(DLL)

Comment: I expect your application has a GUI and not a console

Comment: This library functionality called from application that uses GUI and already open console

Comment: For me this feature has always worked on native c++ regardless of the version of Visual Studio I have used from the 1990s to today using VS2019. I don't know any steps to tell you to use to debug the situation other than using breakpoints and verify that the code in your DLL is running as you expect.

Comment: @AndriyBuchynskyy Does `printf` work if called from the main app code, and is the main app using the CRT at all?

Comment: @dxiv Yes, main app code uses CRT and printf works fine there

Comment: @AndriyBuchynskyy That's odd. I'd check that the file descriptor returned by `fileno(stdout)` is the same when called from the main app vs. the DLL, and I'd also check the return value of the `printf` call in the DLL. Other than that, it sounds like a candidate for step by step debugging down to the metal.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to change your `"SubSystem"` to be `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` then to see the `printf` messages on Visual Studio Output window.

One more thing, `#include <iostream>` is necessary !

Property setting is here:
[image]