# How to print to standard output when using Qt without using qDebug()

Tags: c++, qt5

It seems like when I'm using Qt, `std::cout << "blah"` does not work. It seems to completely ignore all `printf` and `std::cout` statements and refuses to print anything unless I use `qDebug() << "blah"`. Why is this? Can I turn this functionality off?

Comment: This does not work in windows if you don't have a console in a GUI application. Here is a 9 year old answer of mine that is about enabling a console from a windows GUI application: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841522/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841522/487892)

Comment: Have you tried adding a `<< std::endl` at the end of `std::cout << "blah"`?