# Visual Studio Console

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Sorry if I'm being dense, but I can't find the console for Visual Studio. I'm in the subsystem:windows mode because I'm writing an app that requires me to be in this mode. Is there a different method of debugging that doesnt use the console? I have some print statements in my C++ program but I can't find where they are printed, can anyone help me find it?

Comment: Fun-fact: Visual Studio doesn't have one. Instead when you run your project you'll get a separate new conhost window. If you close it, then you will have lost any generated stdout/stderr.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454681/how-to-keep-the-console-window-open-in-visual-c

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/vscpp-step-2-build?view=msvc-170

Comment: No I am talking about visual studio. I'm in the subsystem:windows mode because I'm writing an app that requires me to be in this mode. Is there a different method of debugging that doesnt use the console?

Comment: if you use `subsystem:windows` then obviously you won't get a console unless you create and attach to one

Comment: My old answer shows several ways to create a console: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840942/visual-studio-2012-c-standard-output/13841522#13841522](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840942/visual-studio-2012-c-standard-output/13841522#13841522)

Comment: BTW, you can create a GUI application that has subsystem:console. I do that all the time for my debug builds for Qt applications.

Comment: @drescherjm when I switch to subsystem:windows, I get this error: ```LNK2019 unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)```

Comment: The middle section of my linked answer explains how to get around this error. ***To fix this I had to add the following to the Entry Point setting of the Advanced Linker settings: "wWinMainCRTStartup"***

Comment: @drescherjm, are the quotes part of the statement?

Comment: I don't think so. Related: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=msvc-170) it would be WinMainCRTStartup if you are not using UNICODE

Comment: You can use `OutputDebugString`  as MSalters answered or MessageBox to print something. But I'm curious that  why you want to use console in a Windows app.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use an external terminal, ex. `xterm`, but I think this guide will help you to open and use an integrated terminal in Vscode:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics

Answer (score 0):

Your print statements are currently just lost - you have chosen not to have a console, since you're in a Windows susbsystem.

There's `OutputDebugString`, which does write to the Visual Studio "Output" tab. But it won't format the output for you. You can do some `std::streambuf` magic to make `std::cout` forward to `OutputDebugString`, so you get `std::ostream` formatting.